# The host '...' was not found in the list of allowed hosts. Do you want to open it anyway?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unc

Since updating to Visual Studio Code v. 1.78.2 this warning has been popping up. It is appearing because the folder I am working out of is using a UNC path. I rely on this path.

The [VS help page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_working-with-unc-paths) states:

> configure the host to be allowed via the `security.allowedUNCHosts` setting (for example add server-a when you open a path such as \server-a\path)

Where is this setting?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to Settings `Ctrl + ,` and search for 'allowedUNCHosts'.  You'll find it under the *Security* section.

Note "a restart is required when changing this setting"

[image: a screenshot of vs code settings specifically the security section and the allowed UNCHosts]

Comment: Thanks. In the settings I added the UNC path ```\\gisfile``` and restarted. Same warning.

Comment: Try adding just the server name (sans slashes).

Comment: It worked without the slashes (i.e. ```gisfile```). No more warning.

Comment: same for me:  for wsl.localhost

Comment: not worked for me with `wsl.localhost`, `wsl` and `localhost` as separated entries. When I drag a file from WSL folder to open with vscode, the warning appears. When I click to open with vscode by window's context it works, but open a separated VSCode instance.

Comment: @GiovanCruz Have you tried `wsl$`, per @wrrnlim above?

Comment: @SeanO @wrrnlim thnks, replacing by `wsl$` worked

Comment: For me, adding the WSL extension in the local VScode solved in.

Comment: is there an option for wildcard in the server name like `*.test.myorg`?

Comment: Great answer! Might also encounter the error "Failed to save '{file_name}'... Unable to write file '{file_path}' (Unknown (FileSystemError): UNC Host '{unc_host_name}' access is not allowed. Please update the 'security.allowedUNCHosts' setting if you want to allow this host.)

Answer (score 10):

To those looking for a solution when using `\\wsl$`, adding `wsl.localhost` to the `allowedUNCHosts` option worked for me. [This source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182055#issuecomment-1542768891) indicates that it can be changed in JSON settings as well.

Comment: Adding `wsl$` to allowedUNCHosts fixed it for me

Comment: In my case, adding wsl.localhost to the allowedUNCHosts worked as well

Comment: This worked for me too. VS Code 1.78.2 running on Windows 11 and accessing WSL hosted Debian 11. Thank you @Daniela.

Comment: Adding wsl.localhost to security.allowedUNCHosts in the json settings file worked for me, this should be the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 3):

The May 2023 VSCode 1.79 can also update that setting for you through a confirmation dialog.

See "[**Windows UNC host allowlist improvements**](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_windows-unc-host-allowlist-improvements)":

> As part of an important security fix, VS Code introduced an allowlist for UNC hosts.
> In this milestone, we addressed many of the usability problems reported by Windows users when they have UNC paths in their day-to-day work with VS Code.
>
> ### Dialog improvements
>
> The confirmation dialog to allow a UNC host on startup now updates the security.allowedUNCHosts setting and adds the host when you select the checkbox.
>
> [image: Windows UNC allow dialog]
>
> In addition, clicking the Learn More button no longer closes the dialog.
>
> ### New `security.restrictUNCAccess` setting
>
> A new setting `security.restrictUNCAccess` lets you disable the UNC allowlist for hosts and restore the behavior to how it was before this security fix.
>
> We strongly advise against changing this setting, as it makes your system vulnerable again to the [Information Disclosure Vulnerability](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/security/advisories/GHSA-mmfh-4pv3-39hr).

Answer (score 0):

Map your WSL host to your network (by right clicking on the WSL host in windows explorer and add a drive letter i.e Z), after that you can add any folder in your WSL to your VSCode workspace

Comment: This does work for getting rid of the message however it also means that VSCode won't open in a WSL window with all the advantages that come with that