# Run a node.js program with node.exe in a network folder

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I would like to use VSCode to run a program that is on my Windows computer `c:\test.js` using a version of `node.js` which is in a network folder (`\\servername\folder\node.exe`).

I do not want to install `node.js`, but just refer to the files on the network folder.

I set up the file `launch.json` below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${file}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "\\\\servername\\folder\\node.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run `test.js`, VSCode gives an error `Can't find Node.js binary \\servername\folder\node.exe`.

I can successfully run the program if I copy `node.exe` to my c-drive (`c:\node.exe`), and change `launch.json` to

```
            "runtimeExecutable": "c:\\node.exe"
```

It also works to set the `PATH` to the network folder per [How do I add environment variables to launch.json in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971572/how-do-i-add-environment-variables-to-launch-json-in-vscode).  :

```
            "env": {"PATH": "\\\\servername\\folder"},
            //"runtimeExecutable": "\\\\servername\\folder\\node.exe"
```

I checked to ensure the path to `node.exe` on the network is correct.

Why can't VSCode find this file on the network, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You might need to allow UNC paths via `security.allowedUNCHosts`, or simply create a local CMD/PS script to front the remote node binary.

Comment: @jarmod, thank you for this.  Great insight.  In settings, I added the host `servername`.  I am still getting the same error.  I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Correction:  This worked after I restarted VSCode.  This fixed the issue.  Disabling checking UNCHosts also works.  @jarmod, if you post this as a solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a default security mechanism introduced in VS Code v1.78.1 that prevents access to [UNC paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc) such as `\\server\resource` unless they are explicitly approved.

This setting is controlled as follows:

- add the UNC path to the VS Code security setting `security.allowedUNCHosts`, or
- define a global environment variable `NODE_UNC_HOST_ALLOWLIST` with the backslash-separated list of hostnames to allow

You may need to restart VS Code for these changes to take effect.

You can also simply `net use` the remote resource to map it to a local drive identifier, in which case you don't need to allow the UNC path explicitly.

See [Working with UNC paths](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_working-with-unc-paths) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76236922/the-host-was-not-found-in-the-list-of-allowed-hosts-do-you-want-to-open-i) for more details.